# Product Attribute in Terms and Conditions

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

Magento 1.9.1.0 - One Page Checkout - Terms and Conditions

Our store has one set of main terms and conditions.
A few products have extra T&C's to add to the main set of terms.

We've created a new attribute so that any product that needs the additional data can be displayed at the top of the standard terms.

I can see that Base > Default > Checkout > onepage > agreements.html
is the place to insert the code, but I can't seem to get it displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Note the code on the top of the template:

```
<?php if (!$this->getAgreements()) return; ?>
```

Just make sure to check if you have any active agreements.
Also make sure you have that agreements.phtml loaded by the page(by enabling the template path hints)

Don't forget to check your var/*.log files of course.